# Add refine link for salary calculator

Tags: feature-request, salary-calculator

After the completion of [salary calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary) I can only make a new calculation and should enter all the required fields again. It would be good if there be “refine” link where all fields are filled with previously chosen data:

> [image: refine salary]

Comment: Pressing the back button in the browser already reuses the last form values (Chrome), so all we need is a link that does `javascript:history.back(1)`

Comment: @SamuelLiew Doesn’t work for Chrome on iOS.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Also, the back button resets the value of the location field to its initial _(detected?)_ value for me (Windows, Chrome v69, 64-bit).